# How to add order summary in e-mail templates? Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I want to edit `email templates`. For now i can see billing info, payment info and items. I want to add `order summary` below `items` but i can't find any variable for this section.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with 'order summary' but you can access all data of the order object (i.e. all public methods which return data) in your template, so you should be able to get all the data you need and build the email the way you need. For example `{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}` should give you the total order value

Comment: I mean.. i want to see in email "new order" - total price. I will try with your example

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I mean.. i want to see in email "new order" - total price. I will try with your example. And picture: